# laravel:8 The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

when i try to edit a form then it gives this error: The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.  while my routes are:

Routes:

```
  Route::get('/articles', 'ArticlesController@index');
  Route::post('/articles', 'ArticlesController@store');
  Route::get('/articles/create', 'ArticlesController@create');
  Route::get('/articles/{article}', 'ArticlesController@show');
  Route::get('/articles/{article}/edit', 'ArticlesController@edit');
  Route::get('/articles/{article}', 'ArticlesController@update');
```

Route list:

```
--------+----------+-------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                     | Name | Action                                         | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                       |      | Closure                                        | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | about                   |      | Closure                                        | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user                |      | Closure                                        | api        |
|        |          |                         |      |                                                | auth:api   |
|        | GET|HEAD | articles                |      | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@index  | web        |
|        | POST     | articles                |      | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@store  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | articles/create         |      | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@create | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | articles/{article}      |      | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@update | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | articles/{article}/edit |      | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@edit   | web        |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

controller:

```
public function update($id)
{
        $article = Article::find($id);

        $article->title = request('title');
        $article->excerpt = request('excerpt');
        $article->body = request('body');
        $article->save();

        return redirect('/articles/'. $article->id);
}
```

Comment: Route::put() in route/web.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your routes are `Route::put()`, you only have `Route::get()` and `Route::post()`.

If you're trying to use PUT for the `update` method, you need to declare your route like this:

```
Route::put('/articles/{article}', 'ArticlesController@update');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have not used resource in your routes then use these routes:

web.php

```
Route::get('/articles', 'articles\ArticlesController@index');
Route::get('/articles/create', 'articles\ArticlesController@create');
Route::post('/articles/create', 'articles\ArticlesController@store');
Route::get('/articles/{article}', 'articles\ArticlesController@show');
Route::get('/articles/{article}/edit', 'articles\ArticlesController@edit');
Route::get('/articles/{article}/edit', 'articles\ArticlesController@update');
```

app/Http/controllers:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\articles;

use App\Http\Requests\User\ArticleRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

//---Constructor Function
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth:sanctum');
}//---End of Function Constructor

public function index() {
}

public function create() {
}

public function store(ArticleRequest $request) {
}

public function show($article) {
}

public function edit($article) {
}

public function update(ArticleRequest $request, $article) {
}
?>
```